# how add fix header to autocomplete popup in angular that cannot scroll?

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I want fix header to angular auto complete how can I do that
[here is image what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K54UV.png)

Comment: Can you please specify what component library you are using and give a little more detail e.g. code sample

Answer (score 0):

in order create this ui  add div below to input box, in that div add ngfor loop , on text change filter array show that array below to text box 
below is idea of implementation 
`<div> <!-- parent div -->
    <div>
      <input type="text"> <!-- add event on change and on change filter the array show the array in below div -->
     </div
     <div *ngFor="let item of items"> <!-- this div must be below to input box -->
       <div>item</div><button>Add</button> <!-- on click event add your logic after adding  change the text of button -->
     </div> 
</div>`